# Link to a tabbed section within the same web page

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, tabs, navigation

I have this basic and clean little tab package. See below. HTML, js, and CSS files

I want to navigate by a link from one tabbed section to another.

I tried the only solution I could find which was this:

```
<a id="agree"> location </a> and <a href="#agree"> link </a>
```

but that doesn't work.

I am submitting the code below so you can see what it is I am working with

The html:

```
 <div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Welcome')" id="defaultOpen">Welcome</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Agreement')" id="defaultOpen">Agreement</button>

 </div>
 <div id="Welcome" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Welcome</h3>
 </div>
 <div id="Agreement" class="tabcontent">
 </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.tab {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 15%;
    height: 380px;
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: black;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 85%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 380px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that your two buttons has the same ID. Never use the same ID for HTML elements.